# Insert status date into gridview cell according to status

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, gridview

currently i'm working on a web service system, using ASP.NET and C# as code behind. for the database, we use MS SQL. there's a feature in the system that allows you to view the status of application forms according to Status, let's say Pending, In Progress, Cleared, and Cancelled. the page involves the use of a Gridview, like this (this is only an example)

| ***App Form ID*** | ***Date*** | ***Name*** | ***Status*** | ***Status Date*** |

in my SQL table, there are columns to accomodate the update of the application forms' status, like DatePending, DateInProgress, DateCleared, DateCancelled, i.e. DateInProgress contains dates when an application form has now undergone processing and tagged as In Progress. all of these columns are in one table.

my question now is, how do I get the date for the specific status and display it on the last column of my Gridview? for example, if an application form is cancelled, it should show the Status of the record as Cancelled, and show the date when it was cancelled.

the output should be like this:

| ***App Form ID*** | ***Date*** | ***Name*** | ***Status*** | ***Status Date*** |

|   12345    |   05/20/2013  | Alvin | InProgress | 05/22/2013

|   12346    |   07/01/2013  | Maggy | Cleared | 07/10/2013

|   12347    |   07/05/2013  | Robin | Cancelled | 07/06/2013

if you have further questions/clarifications, feel free to express so. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, I do have one ... what have you tried? It seems like all you need to do is run an sql query depending on your status, and set it, but, if you didn't try anything, I don't see the problem ...

Comment: i have tried doing it from code behind, like getting the content of the status column, if it's In Progress, it would get the corresponding date under the DateInProgress column from the SQL table and display it in the Status Date. problem is, i can't figure out how to. is what i'm trying to do possible? or do i need to do something else?

Comment: where do you initialize your data? can you post that code?

Comment: i don't think i can, it's a big chunk of code, but if it helps, the system is a 3-tier architecture. Data Access, Business Logic, and Presentation layers

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I'd change the structure of my database.  Having columns for statuses and dates won't help you in the long run.  Also, how do you easily identify which is the most current status?  Your query would have to be pretty complicated to deal with this.

A better thing to do would be to have a linked 'status' table with a structure something like this:-

```
AppFormID <---to join to your form table
StatusType <---Pending, cancelled etc
Status Date <---obvious, really
```

Having it set up like this would make your life a hell of a lot easier, and won't restrict you if (when) you decide you want to create new kinds of status.

Comment: the number of status are fixed, so that won't pose much of a problem. the idea you presented is definitely my last resort though.

Comment: It will make your life easier - maybe not in the short term whilst you move your data around, but definitely as you go on, especially if you do decide to change things around at another point.  It will also make your queries easier to build.