# Include "all" option in displaying records in Crystal Reports?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, crystal-reports

Further upgrades to the [web service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19905730/insert-status-date-into-gridview-cell-according-to-status) I am currently working on allows the system to display all records from all branches in a table. My problem now is making all records visible when generating a Crystal Reports file. The generating of reports work fine if a specific branch is selected, but when the user selects the "-- All --" in the dropdown menu, no records display in the .rpt file.

A few notes: the "-- All --" option is added in the code behind, not in the SQL table.

If you need to clarify some things, feel free to ask questions.

**EDIT:**

```
DataRow drBr = branchDS.Tables[0].NewRow();
                if (sessionBankCode == "0")
                {
                    drBr["BranchID"] = 0;
                    drBr["BranchCode"] = "-- All --";
                    drBr["BranchName"] = "-- All --";
                    drBr["BankCode"] = "0";
                    branchDS.Tables[0].Rows.Add(drBr);
                }
                else if (sessionBankCode == "1")
                {
                    drBr["BranchID"] = 0;
                    drBr["BranchCode"] = "-- All --";
                    drBr["BranchName"] = "-- All --";
                    drBr["BankCode"] = "1";
                    branchDS.Tables[0].Rows.Add(drBr);
                }
```

this is how I included the "-- All --" option in the code behind. as for how the "-- All --" option is utilized, stored procedures on the SQL server side use it.

The system is a 3-tier architecture. a .cs file in the Data Access Layer converts the "-- All --" into 'all', then passes it to the stored procedure.

```
if (BranchCode == "-- All --")
                {
                    string brCode = "all";
                    cmdSelect.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BranchCode", brCode);
                }
```

**EDIT 2:** the code below is right after the code that includes the "-- All --" option

```
ddBranches.DataSource = branchDS;
                ddBranches.DataTextField = "BranchName";
                ddBranches.DataValueField = "BranchCode";
                ddBranches.DataBind();
```

Comment: can you update the question with your code? specially how you handle when you select `All` option?

Comment: solved my own problem... re-configured the stored proc in the database,  did some changes in the Code Behind and some other areas, and set up a new .rpt file. works wonders now.

Comment: Would be great if you post it as an answer as opposed to a comment